Calculating EV of poker move
This book, "The Mathematics of Poker," doesn't make sense here.

"It's the flop of a $30$-$60$ holdem game. Player A holds
$A\diamondsuit K\diamondsuit$, and player B holds
$7\clubsuit$$8\clubsuit$.  The flop is $A\clubsuit
 K\spadesuit4\clubsuit$. There is just $195$ in the pot, and AK bets
$30$. B has just eight outs in this case (as the $K\clubsuit$ makes AK a full house). B has enough immediate odds to call with his flush draw on the flop.  His EV is then  $$ \left(\frac{8}{45}\right)(255) - 30 = 15.33. $$
On the turn, if the draw misses, there are two cases. In one case, an ace or king will have hit on the turn and he will be unable to win the pot, or be \textit{drawing dead}.  This occurs $\frac{4}{45}$ of the time. The remaining $\frac{41}{45}$ of the time he will have  $$
\left(\frac{8}{44}\right)(375) - 60 = 8.18 $$ of positive expectation
from calling.
His total expectation on the turn, again using equation $1.11$, is: $$
 \langle B, \text{turn}\rangle = p(A \text{ or } K) (\langle B, A \text{ or } K \text{
 hits}\rangle) + p(\text{other})(\langle B, \text{other}\rangle)$$ $$ \langle B, \text{turn}\rangle =
 \left(\frac{4}{45}\right)(0) + \left(\frac{41}{45}\right)(8.18) $$ $$
 \langle B, \text{turn}\rangle = 7.45 $$
So in this case, the play on the flop would go A bets - B calls. Then if the draw did not hit on the turn, A would bet again and B would be able to profitably call again (because calling is worth more than zero from folding)."

Here is how I would calculate B's EV on the flop. On the turn, B's EV is 8/44 * 375 - 60 = 8.18. On the flop, there are three situations for the turn. Either A hits the full house, B hits his flush, or neither of those things happen. So B's EV on the flop is $$4/45 * 0 + 8/45 * 255 - 30 + 33/45 * 8.18 = 21.32$$
I also don't get the way it's conditioning on the fact on the turn the flush doesn't hit. Even in that case, the denominator should not be 45, it should be like 37, right? Since 45-8 = 37.

I expect that users here are generally familiar with poker jargon, but possibly not all the details.  No idea what a $30-60$ game is, for instance.  You might reach a broader audience if you get rid of some of the jargon and write in more standard vocabulary.  Just a thought.

I don't understand what you're saying with the denominator being 37, but I do agree that $21.33 is the perfect information / perfect play EV from calling (assuming it's a 30/60 limit game) and that it's unclear what is going on in the passage.
